# Explain the Behavior of Speedup vs No. of Processes graph for Integral Using Trapezoid Method

Tags: graph, parallel-processing, mpi

**Task:**
I implemented the integral using MPI in C language:
[Integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eCuc.png)

$$ \int_0^{1}(4/(1+x^2)),dx  $$

I have to analyze the Speedup vs No. of processes for different values of N where N is the number of segments that we divide the integral curve into.
I got the output for different values of *n* (No. of processes = [1,12] and N=1000, 10^6 and 10^8 and plotted it using python.

My graph:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF8fF.png)

The graph for N=10^8 is near "ideal" and for N=1000 is almost flat.

Can someone explain why the graph behaves like this? I don't understand how S = T_1/T_s explains this behavior.

Thank you.

UPDATE:
[Integral Implementation](https://pastebin.com/uwMFypq2)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
 
//int const n = 10e8;
 
double f(double x) {
    return (4 / (1 + x * x));
}
 
double partialArea(double indexSegment, int n, double h) {
    double area = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        area += (0.5 * h * (f(indexSegment * h + i * h) + f(indexSegment * h + (i + 1) * h)));
    }
    return area;
}
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int myrank, size;
    MPI_Status Status; // MPI data type
    double integral = 0.0;
    double startwtime, endwtime;
    double a = 0.0, b = 1.0;
    int n;
 
    if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <n>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
   }
 
    n = atoi(argv[1]); // Get n from command line argument
    double h = (b - a) / n;
 
    /* MPI programs start with MIP_Init; all "N" processes exist thereafter */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
 
    /* find out how big the world of processes is */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
 
    /* and this process's rank is */
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
 
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    startwtime = MPI_Wtime();
    if (myrank == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            integral += (0.5 * h * (f(a + i * h) + f(a + (i + 1) * h)));
        }
        printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Integral by sequential: %lf\n", integral);
        printf("Size (number of processes): %d\n", size);
        printf("N (number of small segments): %d\n", n);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
    double sequential_time = endwtime - startwtime;
 
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    startwtime = MPI_Wtime();
 
    int k = n / size; // number of small intervals 1 process has to work with
 
    int remain = n % size;
    int for_main = k + remain; // if there is a remainder n/size, then it is for the main process
    double result = 0.0;
    double partial = 0.0;
    int index;
 
    if (myrank == 0) {
        result += partialArea(0, for_main, h);
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(&partial, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            result += partial;
        }
        printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Integral by the addition of all parts: %lf\n", result);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
    } else {
        index = for_main + k * (myrank - 1);
        partial = partialArea(index, k, h);
        MPI_Send(&partial, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Rank %d: Partial Integral I%d = %lf\n", myrank, myrank, partial);
    }
 
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
    double process_time = endwtime - startwtime;
 
    if (myrank == 0) {
        printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Sequential time: %lf\n", sequential_time);
        printf("Process time: %lf\n", process_time);
        printf("Speed up: %lf\n", sequential_time / process_time);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Creating threads take time. Sharing the work to do also take time (much faster, but still *not free*). If the sequential computation is faster than creating threads, it does not worth it. This is the same thing in real life : if you call your friends living in other cities and ask them to come so to (physically) help you to cook a meal, then there is good chance it does not worth it, unless you plan to prepare a big meal for a big party ;) . For more information, please read : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law .

Comment: You should really include your code. Here are random guesses as to what you may be doing wrong. 1. MPI is process based. Make sure you don't include the process creation in your timing. 2. Your code (which you haven't given) should only do a reduce at the end. Does it? Anything else will probably swamp your actual computation.

Comment: This is MPI, so some overhead is spent in communications, not in "threads creation". For small `N`, the overhead is typically too high vs the gain of parallelism, but for larger `N`, the overhead is typically smaller, and hence a near optimal speedup.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn and use MPI_Reduce() !

Answer (score 0):

You let rank 0 do a series of blocking receives. That means that the MPI portion of your code has a running time linearly *increasing* with the number of processes. Use `MPI_Reduce` instead.